# Where to edit for increase in memory in PHP ini file?

Tags: php

Hi I do have a PHP script which reads text file. when text file size is above the certain limit script gives error and stops. when I divide files into two it works. so where is that settings in PHP to increase read file memory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The setting is `memory_limit` and you can change it in the php.ini file for all scripts, or (better) just change it in the code for the one script that is causing you problems:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');
```

Comment: +1 for the inside the code approach, and here's the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.resource-limits) for this.

Comment: Have in mind if you have memory_limit set in more than one spot (included php files) PHP will use one that was found last.

Answer (score 4):

There are three ways to change the memory_limit for your PHP script(s):

1) A quick solution would be to add the following line into your root directory .htaccess file:

```
php_value memory_limit 32M
```

---

2) In your PHP Config file (php.ini) -- Location depends on your Apache/server setup.
Search the file for `memory_limit` and change to your desired value:

```
memory_limit= 32M
```

Then restart your apache server.

---

3) You can also specify the memory limit in your PHP script:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '32M');
```