# Issue in displaying large no of records on view file in codeigniter without using pagination

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm fetching list of users from mysql db table & displaying on the view file of my codeigniter application, I'm not using pagination, I want to show all records on same page . But only partial data is displaying on the page, I have 3000 records but only 1000 to 1500 records gets shown on page. after that the script dies down, I tried changing `max_execution_time` `max_input_time memory_limit` but no help.

```
public function UsersCe14($sort = NULL, $column = NULL) {
   if (!empty($sort)) {
        switch ($column) {
           case 'ID':
               $sortColumn = '`id`';
               break;
           case 'Username':
               $sortColumn = '`username`';
               break;
           case 'FirstName':
               $sortColumn = '`first_name`';
               break;
           case 'LastName':
               $sortColumn = '`last_name`';
               break;
           case 'Email':
               $sortColumn = '`email`';
               break;
           case 'Country':
               $sortColumn = '`country`';
               break;
           case 'Registered':
               $sortColumn = "`core_entities`.`created`";
               break;
           case 'LastLogin':
               $sortColumn = '`last_login`';
               break;
           case 'Suspended':
               $sortColumn = '`suspended`';
               break;
           case 'Active':
               $sortColumn = '`is_active`';
               break;
       }
       $data['sort'] = $sort == 'DESC' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
       $sortColumn = $sortColumn . " " . $sort;
   } else {
       $data['sort'] = 'DESC';
       $sortColumn = "`core_entities`.`created` DESC";
   }

   if (!$this->biipmi_auth->is_logged_in()) {
       redirect(site_url('admin/login'));
       return;
   }

   if (!$this->biipmi_auth->is_admin()) {
       redirect(site_url());
       return;
   }

   $this->load->model('biipmi_entity/biipmi_person_model');
   $data['users'] = $this->biipmi_person_model->get_persons(NULL, NULL, $sortColumn, NULL, NULL, array("email", "country", "last_login"), 'reference', array("2"));
   $data['page_title'] = 'biipmi Admin - CE14 Users';
   $data['main_content'] = 'admin/users/persons_ce14';
   $this->load->view('admin/includes/template', $data);
}
```

Comment: Where is you `model` ? are you sure that your `model` is fetching all data ?

Comment: Seems is your memory problem, try to retrieve less fields, or try to increase the memory. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660517/where-to-edit-for-increase-in-memory-in-php-ini-file