# Reading log file via PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a web app which generates hundreds of emails per day and one of the most common support requests is why has my email not arrived - in most cases, the mail has been sent by us but has gotten delayed or rejected by the receiver

The only way we can tell is to SSH into the server, open exim log file and search for the email address which is time consuming and also potentially "dangerous" as we don't want support staff logging in via SSH in case they do something dumb.

We want to have a simple way of displaying the contents of /var/log/exim/main.log via https in our support portal. The file is just under 1MB in size at the moment.

At this stage we have used:

```
$file = file('/var/log/exim/main.log');
foreach ($file as $row) {
    print $row."<br>";
}
```

We have done it this way as it shows each line in its own line and makes it more readable - it works fine for the around the first 1000 lines/rows and then the pagination "breaks".

If we print the array using

```
print_r($file);
```

it shows fine but as soon as we loop through it stops working at entry 1054 in the array.

For example, we get:

```
2014-03-24 01:06:45 cwd=/home/domain/public_html 3 args: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i 
2014-03-24 01:06:45 1WRtLh-0001ke-5K <= apache@web01.domain.com U=apache P=local S=810 T="Message" from for email@email.com
2014-03-24 01:06:45 cwd=/var/spool/exim 3 args: /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1WRtLh-0001ke-5K 
2014-03-24 01:06:48 1WRtLh-0001ke-5K => email@email.com F= R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp S=827 H=mx1.mx [1.1.1.1] C="250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as C7E5F301206" 2014-03-24 01:06:48 1WRtLh-0001ke-5K Completed 2014-03-24 01:10:26 cwd=/home/domain/public_html/send 3 args: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i 2014-03-24 01:10:26 1WRtPG-0001lw-7y <= apache@web01.domain.com U=apache P=local S=825 T="Message 2" from 


for email2@email.com 2014-03-24 01:10:26 cwd=/var/spool/exim 3 args: /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1WRtPG-0001lw-7y 2014-03-24 01:10:29 1WRtPG-0001lw-7y => email2@email.com F=
```

and from then on the pagination is broken.

Is there a limit to the size of a file or number of items in an array read in this way? If not, any idea why this is happening?

Comment: As far as I know the only limitations you have are the one you create on the server. An array can only be as large as the max memory limit you allow on the server..

Comment: You might have more luck with fopen/fgets/fclose as this would not fill your memory nor create large arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks OK and should work. I guess there is some problem with the memory allocation. The following link could be of some help.

[Where to edit for increase in memory in PHP ini file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660517/where-to-edit-for-increase-in-memory-in-php-ini-file)

Answer (score 0):

If it's just an email address you're searching for, why not just have a form where they can submit the email address they're searching for, and have your php script read through the file searching for that address? There's no reason to manually do the search that way, unless i'm misunderstanding the question?

Comment: The actual email address is not shown on all the relevant lines so I need lines before and after to see the whole log entry so not sure this would work

Comment: @bhttoan it would be easy, once found, to include the 5 (or any amount) of lines before and after the email address.