# Out of memory PHP

Tags: html, memory

I am using `simple_html_dom.php` to read html data from a very big website.I have a new hosting and upload my files there.When i run this file i am getting this error

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 378011648) (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in /home/mysite/public_html/myfolder/simple_html_dom.php on line 1396
```

I have these lines on top of both files

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

echo ini_get('memory_limit'); prints **2048M**

Inspite of this how i can get this error?

I know there are alot on internet about this issue..I read these also [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660517/where-to-edit-for-increase-in-memory-in-php-ini-file)

echo phpinfo() ; give me memory_limit = 2048M but still the same error

Comment: Your process is already using 360.5 MB of memory. This is probably a per-user or per-process memory limit on the server. Setting the memory limit to 2 GB is not going to change anything. You need to change your implementation.

Comment: How i can change Implementation? I have on CPANEL access...

Comment: I mean change your code.

Comment: How i can change code,i need all what i coded for.

Comment: How can I know? You haven't shown any of your code, or even explained anything about what the code does.

Comment: I am doing crawling,reading a website and get contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After those 2 lines add to your php script:

```
echo ini_get('memory_limit');
```

to check if your memory limit is in fact 2048M

On all hostings there are limits, so maybe you cannot change your memory limit to 2048M but you can to for example 1024M. You should check your hosting plan

Comment: So you have to check your hosting plan memory limits

Comment: How can i check this?

Comment: You should look at your hosting provider website or e-mail your administrator to get details about your hosting plan. Many hosting accounts have limit for example only 256 MB and you cannot do anything with this. In this case you should upgrade your account or choose another hosting provider

Comment: echo phpinfo() ; give me memory_limit = 2048M but still the same error

Comment: You need to check other hosting limits. As  Jonathon Reinhart said, your script uses only 360.5 MB memory not 2048 MB so it seems there are other limits on your hosting